# Mapping claims when federating with another Azure AD B2C tenant

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have followed the [Set up sign-up and sign-in with an Azure AD B2C account from another Azure AD B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-b2c?pivots=b2c-user-flow#configure-azure-ad-b2c-as-an-identity-provider) article using the `user flow` policy type.

Everything works as expected until I try to customise the identity provider claims mapping in the [Configure Azure AD B2C as an identity provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-b2c?pivots=b2c-user-flow#configure-azure-ad-b2c-as-an-identity-provider) section.

I am attempting to map a custom user attribute to the `User ID` claim, the mapping works if I map it to a different claim e.g. `Given Name`.

For example, I have a custom user attribute named `Clock Number` in the Fabrikam B2C tenant, when I run the sign in/up user flow the `sub` claim is the `ObjectID` of the user and I can see the custom attribute in the token.

[image: Custom claim appears in token]

In the Contoso B2C tenant, I map `extension_ClockNumber` to `Given Name` and run the sign in/up user flow the clock number is correctly mapped to `given_name` however I am not sure what value is mapped to the `sub` claim – it is not the `ObjectID` of the user as it was in the previous example.

[image: Wrong sub claim]

When I map `extension_ClockNumber` to `User ID` and run the user flow it is not mapping as it did to `Given Name`, I would have expected the value of `extension_ClockNumber` to appear in the `sub` claim.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For anybody that sees this in the future I am no longer attempting to map the custom attribute.

When signing in from one Azure AD B2C account from another Azure AD B2C account the "sub" claim contains the users object id from the root e.g. Contoso.

This means that I have to look for a federated identity to retrieve the IssuerAssignedId which will be the object id of the user in the other tenant e.g. Fabrikam.  This can be achieved via:

**GET** [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName,identities&$filter=id eq '6fa2f184-e0cb-456d-9686-fffb2ef71441'](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName,identities&$filter=id%20eq%20%276fa2f184-e0cb-456d-9686-fffb2ef71441%27)

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens?utm_source=pocket_mylist#claims-in-access-tokens) says about the `oid` payload cliam:

> If a single user exists in multiple tenants, the user will contain a
> different object ID in each tenant - they are considered different
> accounts, even though the user logs into each account with the same
> credentials.

Comment: Hi, did you have issues with the email claim mapping? mine is not working and every time a new user signed up with the other B2C tenant Account (Fabrikan) into Contoso, it is asking for the email in the Detail (Attributes Collect) screen.